# ElasticSearchSink connector infers wrong mapping from the schemas of Kafka messages?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am newbie to Kafka Connect and currently trying to solve something weird happening with one particular topic.

I am sourcing data from multiple tables via Debezium connector for PostgreSQL, and the table in question initially had columns `created_at` and `updated_at`,  `timestamp without time zone`. I am using AVRO and type field was of type LONG.
Shortly after the first set of testing, I changed that column to `timestamp with timezone` and a v2 of value schema for message was properly generated. Sinking records to another database is okay, but when trying to sink to ElasticSearch, the mappings of this table somewhat are getting inferred from v1 of the schema in Schema Registry.

**Mappings**:

```
{
  "my_index_1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "created_by" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "updated_at" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "updated_by" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sink connector:**

```
{
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "topics": "local-my_topic1,local-my_topic2,local-my_topic3",
            "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
            "write.method": "UPSERT",
            "key.ignore": "false",
            "schema.ignore": "false",
            "behavior.on.null.values": "DELETE",
            "tasks.max": "1",
            "transforms": "dropPrefix,extractKeyFromStruct",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"local-(.*).public.(.*)$",
            "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"local_$1_$2",
            "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
            "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.field":"id"
    }
```

The **error** from worker -

```
...
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [created_at] of type [long] in document with id 'a59cd73f-b1d9-4a42-9357-01d601bca074'. Preview of field's value: '2023-06-01T08:07:12.206Z']]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=For input string: \"2023-06-01T08:07:12.206Z\"]];\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:496)
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. :)